# A lanolin-enriched puzzle

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

*Many-time solver/first-time setter and so feedback is strongly solicited. This puzzle was written by me for a set of puzzles to celebrate a particular anniversary, but was not used.*

---

Divide the following words into sets of three:

| Words |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BAG | BLED | CORRAL | DELHI | DURER |
| HOGARTH | LEAD | MATISSE | PARKING | PER |
| PHOSPHORUS | PURSE | SOFTLY | TRAMLINE | YELLOW |

**What anniversary is being marked?**

HINT:

> The five sets each have single word associations, at least three of which should be unambiguous. The five words form a title.

Comment: Is the word-property tag intended? Do you mean connect-wall?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I think that I mean that tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anniversary being marked is:

> 100 years since the birth of the musical entertainer **[Donald Swann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Swann)**, one half of the comic duo [Flanders and Swann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanders_and_Swann). This occasion fell on 30 September 2023, the date this puzzle was published.

The five sets of three are as follows:

> **Group 1: Words that can be represented by the letter 'P' (or 'pee')**
>  PARKING (on road signs and maps), PHOSPHORUS (in the Periodic Table), SOFTLY (in sheet music).
>
>  **Group 2: Words that become another word when 'PO' is inserted**
>  CORRAL → COR**PO**RAL, PURSE → PUR**PO**SE, TRAMLINE → TRAM**PO**LINE
>
>  **Group 3: Words that can precede 'BELLY'**
>  [DELHI Belly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelers%27_diarrhea), [LEAD Belly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_Belly), YELLOW Belly (a coward).
>
>  **Group 4: Words that can follow 'BUM'**
>  BumBAG, BumBLED, BumPER
>
>  **Group 5: Artists (i.e. 'Draw-ers')**
>  [Albrecht DURER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_D%C3%BCrer), [William HOGARTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Hogarth), [Henri MATISSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Matisse).

Altogether, this gives us the clue phrase:

> **"Pee Po Belly Bum Drawers"**, often stylised as "P** P* B**** B** D******" - a song comparing the use of profanity among the intelligentsia to playground swearing. A video of the song can be seen on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSrXqOI9988).

As to why this puzzle is 'lanolin-enriched':

> @fljx points out in comments that in the introduction to the Flanders and Swann song '[A Transport of Delight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=32&v=0YWcaGgOG_8)', Swann is jokily introduced as "the well-known pianist, composer, linguist, **also contains lanolin**, Donald Swann".

Comment: For the Lanolin link: https://youtu.be/0YWcaGgOG_8?t=32

Comment: Or (the only transcript I can find including the intro) https://usuaris.tinet.cat/klunn/poems.html#bus

Comment: @fljx Aha, thank you! I've been scratching my head over that...